# Multiple FIN packets received by server

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I am running a port forwarding proxy on a linux box. All the connections from the browser are rerouted to a different port using the proxy.

Whenever the proxy receives (recv()) 0 bytes, I close the connection with the outer world (opened through proxy) using shutdown. When that connection is closed, I close the connection with the browser. The arrangement looks like follows:

```
   Connection Out                     Local Connection
```

Outer World <-----> Forward Proxy(Local Box)<-------> Client(Local Box)

However, I receive multiple data packets of length 0 on "local connection" for the same socket before it is closed. This happens when proxy is trying to close the connection with the outer world.

My understanding is TIME_WAIT value is 2*MSL and that comes out to be pretty high,(hundreds of seconds). However, I see multiple 0 byte packets in a fraction of a second. Am I doing something wrong? Or my understanding is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: How are you seeing this ? If read() or recv() returns 0, you are not supposed to call read() or recv() again on that socket.

Comment: Hey this solves the problem. I do select() on all the file descriptors. If select() returns the fd then I do recv() on it. If I recv(), 0 then I initiate the close process. I wonder why select() would continuously return me this file descriptor even though I have read it once I understood it has returned 0 bytes.                       Your solution solves my problem. I just had this question in my mind.

Comment: select() is telling you that the EOS condition is still there. shutdown() only closes the connection in the outbound direction: it does nothing to the inbound direction. Code that doesn't stop reading after EOS is unacceptable in any program. Also, MSL is sixty seconds: 2*MSL is two minutes, not 'hundreds of seconds'.